# Tcl OO method 'new' failing to override

Tags: tcl

Why does the 'new' method not seem to allow overriding in Tcl OO?

```
% oo::class create A {
    method new {} { puts "In A's new"; return [next] }
}
::A
% A new
::oo::Obj15
% A new
::oo::Obj16
% info class definition A new
{} { puts "In A's new"; return [next] }
% info class call A new
{method new ::A method}
```

A's new method exists, but doesn't seem to get called when "A new" is executed.
Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 3):

The methods you define in a class can be invoked on an **instance** of the class:

```
% oo::class create A {
    method new {} { puts "In A's new"; return [next] }
}
::A
% set obj [A new]
::oo::Obj12
% $obj new
In A's new
no next method implementation
```

If you want to augment the `new` method of class A, use `self`:

```
% oo::class create A {
    self method new {} { puts "In A's new"; return [next] }
}
::A
% A new
In A's new
::oo::Obj12
```

Comment: Or define a subclass of `oo::class` that makes `A`. Unlike some languages, Tcl is happy with you subclassing classes themselves (to make metaclasses); it is a natural thing to do when you want to do trickery with instance manufacturing.

Answer (score 1):

As documented at http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/class.htm#M10, `MyClass new` calls [the class **constructor**](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/define.htm#M6) not a method named "new".

You want

```
oo::class create A {
    constructor {} { puts "In A's new"; return [next] }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn. Yes, I understand the constructor is called but that has no control over the instance of object returned, I assumed from the docs that new and create could be overloaded, but I guess not. There was an old Wiki Tcl article (https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/TclOO+Tricks) that seemed to suggest that 'new' could be overloaded. I guess the article is OOD and incorrect now.

Comment: Do you need to use the word "new" to create this object?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `$obj $mth`, the `$mth` method is looked up on the `$obj` object, with all its contributions from the class hierarchy. In the case of `A new`, the *object* is the *class* `A`, and the method is called `new`, that has an implementation supplied by `oo::class` (which makes the object structures, allocates a name, calls the constructors with the arguments you gave, and returns the fully-qualified name).

You can intercept that by defining a `new` method on `A` itself, or by mixing in a suitable class into the object, or by using a metaclass. (All of those will want to use `next` to delegate actual construction to the standard method.)

## Scheme 1: object method on class object

```
oo::class create A {
    self method new {} { puts "In A's new"; return [next] }
}
```

```
# Variant of scheme 1; syntactically different, makes same thing
oo::class create A
oo::objdefine A {
    method new {} { puts "In A's new"; return [next] }
}
```

## Scheme 2: mixin into class object

```
oo::class create B {
    method new {} { puts "In [self]'s new"; return [next] }
}

oo::class create A {
    self mixin B
}
```

## Scheme 3: metaclass

(Metaclasses are just classes that subclass `oo::class` itself.)

```
oo::class create C {
    superclass oo::class
    method new {} { puts "In [self]'s new"; return [next] }
}

C create A {
    # any other method definitions you want here
}
```

Metaclasses are definitely the best option when you want to make whole families of these things, and mixins allow for a more targeted approach. (Yes, the capabilities overlap.)